# Setting an integer equal to the amount of values inside an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to create a counter to see how many values are allocated in an array of x*52 size.

So if int player1[i] can store x amount of values and after feeding in or taking out values every iteration, i want to create a counter to keep track of it. Any ideas on how i can get this started? Thank you

A sample bit of code to explain my problem. so after i cout a part of my array, i want to remove it and after its removed i want to create an int that remembers the new amount of values in the array.

I have to use two arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class around this array, add a counter field to it, and create a method, like setValueAt(int x, int y). You can increment your counter there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `std::vector` as it remembers how many items are inside it.  You can retrieve that information by using `std::vector::size()`.

Comment: forgot to mention that i have to use two arrays